# file tranfer in python using ftp

Tags: python

New to python. I'm trying to transfer files in python using FTP on same IP, this is the program.

```
import os
import ftplib
import sys

            ftp = ftplib.FTP(ipaddress)
            ftp.login(username = user,passwd = password)
            ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
            if ext in (".txt"):
                ftp.cwd(filepathDestination)
                ftp.storlines("STOR " + filename, open(filename))
            else:
                ftp.storbinary("STOR " + filename, open(filename, "rb"), 1024)
        else:
            print 'Wrong IP'
```

and the error which it is showing is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftp.py", line 35, in <module>
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(ipaddress)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ftplib.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ftplib.py", line 131, in connect
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 567, in create_connection
    raise error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Is your FTP server running?

Comment: The code that comes _after_ the `ftplib.FTP()` call isn't useful... if it's not a simple case of the FTP server not running, we'd need to see the code _before_ (e.g. how is `ipaddress` defined?).

Comment: ipaddress is defined like 123.111.120.10